# How is an empty Set an initial object

Tags: category-theory

(I'm using Haskell syntax)

So I have an initial object, which I call $\text{Void}$. The prerequisite for an inital object is $\forall X \in \text{Hask.} \exists ! f : \text{Void} \to X$. But how is that true?
Can't I just say:

```
f :: Void -> Int
f _ = 1

f' :: Void -> Int
f _ = 2

(...)
```

The same applies to Set, with a set $I \in \text{Set}$ such that $\forall X \in \text{Set}. \exists! f : I \rightarrow X$, where $I = \emptyset$::

$$
f: \emptyset \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \\ 
f(x) = 1 \\ 
f': \emptyset \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \\ 
f'(x) = 2 \\ 
...
$$

Of course I can't call any of them, because the prerequisites of having an element of type Void will never hold true, but still, I can create as many functions as I want.

And if pattern matching is *illegal*, then how can I even create a single function?

```
f'' :: Void -> a
-- how is this ok?
```

Comment: Who claimed that Hask has an initial object? Anyways, f and f' are 'equal' in the sense that they give the same value on each term of type Void if Void is 'empty', trivially.

Comment: @Ben [Bartosz Milewski does](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zer1aFgj4aU), but he also kind of disregards the existence of Bottom in Hask. But even without Bottom I don't see how my question would change.

Comment: You give a caveat that you're "using Haskell syntax." Are you just using that syntax to ask a question about the category $\operatorname{Set}$, or are you actually asking about the category of Haskell types and terms? The answers will be very different in those cases.

Comment: @MikeHaskel Actually both answers would be of interest to me. I will clarify my question.

Comment: Actually, it is not even clear if Hask is a category at all: [see Andrej Bauer's blogpost](http://math.andrej.com/2016/08/06/hask-is-not-a-category/). Of course, it does not keep you from wondering if there is a unique arrow from `Void` to a given type though. But take a look at the comments and you should find the beggining of the answer: `f` and `f'` are not syntactically equal, but they are in every semantic model. It seems to be a kind of _intensional vs extensional_ issue.

Comment: Why the Empty set is initial still doesn't make sense to me. The function f() can be mapped to any non-empty set (object in this case) in many different ways (so the morphisms are NOT unique). Say consider the functions f:{}->{1,2,3}. Let f()=1 or g()=2 or h()=3 which are different morphisms to the same object {1,2,3} from the empty set. Thus, the empty set is not initial. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: @Pinocchio You don't need to post to every comment... Wait a second, I will create a new answer, where I explain it myself

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with Haskell, but let me give an answer from category theory; I believe that this should transfer over to a large extent.

The function "$f(x)=2$" isn't really a function from $\emptyset$ - rather, its *restriction* to $\emptyset$ is. And the restrictions of $x\mapsto 2$ and $x\mapsto 1$ to $\emptyset$ are the same.

This becomes clear when we think of functions set-theoretically: a function from $A$ to $B$ is a susbet $f$ of $A\times B$ such that for each $a\in A$ there is exactly one $b\in B$ with $(a, b)\in f$.

Now of course, when working with Haskell the phrase "thinking of functions set-theoretically" is probably a bit cringe-inducing; but it nonetheless has its place here. In the category **Set**, a morphism from $A$ to $B$ is a triple $(f, A, B)$ where $f\subseteq A\times B$ is a *set-theoretic* function from $A$ to $B$.

The key here is that, in both category theory (or rather, the specific category **Set** - there are other "categories of sets") and set theory, we identify it with its graph, not its intensional definition; so "map everything to $2$" and "map everything to $1$," while intensionally different, yield the same set-theoretic function.

Comment: Why the Empty set is initial still doesn't make sense to me. The function f() can be mapped to any non-empty set (object in this case) in many different ways (so the morphisms are NOT unique). Say consider the functions f:{}->{1,2,3}. Let f()=1 or g()=2 or h()=3 which are different morphisms to the same object {1,2,3} from the empty set. Thus, the empty set is not initial. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: @Pinocchio You're conflating the *definition* of a function (e.g. "send everything to $2$") with the function itself (namely, the triple (set of ordered pairs, domain, codomain)). The only function from $\{\}$ to $\{1,2,3\}$ is $(\{\},\{\}, \{1,2,3\})$, since there is nothing in the domain to "pair up" in the first place. This is in fact exactly what I was saying in my answer: read the last sentence in particular.

Comment: It might be better to consider a non-empty situation first. Consider the *definitions of* functions "divide by four" and "subtract three." Do you see why these define the *same* function from $\{4\}$ to $\{1\}$ (and that there is in fact only one function from $\{4\}$ to $\{1\}$)? The same thing is going on here: even if you write different definitions, they're not necessarily naming different functions.

Comment: @Pinocchio Similarly to quantification over the emptyset, the "no counterexample" interpretation can be useful. We have two functions $f,g$ from $\{\}$ to $\{1,2,3\}$, and I claim $f=g$. Since $f$ and $g$ clearly have the same domain and codomain, I'm correct exactly as long as *there is no counterexample to my claim* - that is, $$f=g\quad\iff\quad\forall 
x\in\{\}(f(x)=g(x)).$$ But this statement is vacuously true, and so indeed $f=g$ - that is, any two functions from $\emptyset$ to $\{1,2,3\}$ are equal.

Comment: I think it makes sense to me that $f \subseteq A \times B$. What I suggested is the 3 different function to be $f=(Nothing,1),g=(Nothing,2),h=(Nothing,3)$ since $a \in \emptyset$ is nothing. They seem 3 different constant functions. I think I understand we need to satisfy $\forall a \in A, \exists ! b \in B : (a,b) \in f$ for a function $f$. If $A = \emptyset$ I is see why the definition is satisfied vacuously, I just don't see how it tells me if each $f$ that satisfies it are unique or different. I need to keep re-reading your answer and comments. Thanks for the help.

Comment: in other words I consider functions different if there is some input where the input is the same but the output is different.

Comment: @Pinocchio "in other words I consider functions different if there is some input where the input is the same but the output is different." But there's **no input at all**, since any input would have to be an *element* of $\emptyset$!

Comment: isn't that what it means to call the function with the empty argument? $f()$? There is no input at all! :D

Comment: That is, "$f=\{(Nothing, 1)\}$" does **not** describe a function with domain $\emptyset$, it describes a function with domain $\{Nothing\}$. And $\emptyset\not=\{Nothing\}$ - the left hand side has no elements but the right hand side has one element.

Comment: @Pinocchio "here is no input at all!" So there's no input which can yield different outputs ...

Comment: @Pinocchio "isn't that what it means to call the function with the empty argument?" You **can't** call a function with no argument. "$f()$" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Seems I was confused because of the following: "The interpretation of a constant symbol $c$ of $L$ is a function $c^{\mathcal A}: A^0 \to A$ Since $A^0$ has just one element. $c^{\mathcal A}$ is uniquely determined by its value at this element." Ok so $A^0$ is not the empty set. So what is it then?

Comment: @Pinocchio In general, $X^Y$ is the set of functions from $X$ to $Y$. In particular, $A^0$ is the set of functions from $0$ (conflated with $\emptyset$) to $A$; there is exactly one of these, namely the empty function. So $A^0$ is a one-element set, and in particular a map from $A^0$ to $A$ *picks out a single element of $A$.*

Comment: also I think it seems confusing because in any programming language I've ever used doing $f()$ is totally valid. There isn't anything illegal about doing that, which looks exactly like calling a function with "Void" (although we  shouldn't be able to instantiate an object of type Void or nothing).

Comment: @Pinocchio There are meaningful differences between mathematics and computer science.

Comment: Ok I found a way that makes sense to me. A function $f$ is a subset from $A \times B$ so in particular $f = \{ (a,b) : a \in \emptyset, b \in B \}$. Since we cannot "instantiate" an $a$ then that set is empty. It's really counter intuitive for me because I "visualize functions" as taking things from one side and mapping things to the other. So how exactly does the input space being the empty set looks like and how do the mapping arrows to sets look like? Is the unique map from the empty set to any other set just the function that doesn't exist? So the "arrows" from left to right don't exist?

Comment: and the non-existent arrows **is the unique morphism** linking the empty set to any other set?

Comment: @Pinocchio Minor typo correction: $f$ is *a subset of* $\{(a,b):a\in\emptyset, b\in B\}$, with the property that for each $a\in \emptyset$ there is exactly one $b\in B$ with $(a,b)\in f$. Important correction: "Is the unique map from the empty set to any other set just the function that doesn't exist?" Is the emptyset just the set that doesn't exist? No - you're conflating "has no elements" (which you can phrase very weirdly as "all its elements don't exist") with "doesn't exist."

Comment: You are right. Oops some typos. I think I got it now though! The morphism from $\emptyset \to A$ (any $A$) is just the $f = \emptyset$. Thats really all there is to it, it seems. Thanks this was extremely productive/useful. I think now I understand 100% what functions really are.

Comment: @Pinocchio Yup - glad to help!

Comment: just out of curiosity, did you mention the "no counter example interpretation" because you saw my other questions/answers related to vacuous truths/falsehoods? (btw thanks again! :D )

Answer (score 3):

For $\mathsf{Set}$, the morphism $0 \to X$ is simply the empty function (i.e. view a function as a subset of the cartesian product, choose the empty subset).

I do not know if this is ideal, but you can express this in Haskell as:

```
data Void

i :: Void -> a
i x = case x of {}
```

You need to run GHC with -XEmptyCase.

Comment: Why the Empty set is initial still doesn't make sense to me. The function f() can be mapped to any non-empty set (object in this case) in many different ways (so the morphisms are NOT unique). Say consider the functions f:{}->{1,2,3}. Let f()=1 or g()=2 or h()=3 which are different morphisms to the same object {1,2,3} from the empty set. Thus, the empty set is not initial. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think what confused me when I wrote the question is the Haskell syntax.
You got to remember that the `_` character is just a syntactic sugar. It means "for all remaining cases, assign that value". If I had realized that, I probably wouldn't have posed that question. Because "technically" it should look like this:

```
f :: Void -> Int
```

Because there is not even a first case. Saying "all remaining cases", although there are zero cases is like saying, "Every person in this room is a doctor.", where the room is empty. There is still no doctor in the room.

Also another thing that is important to remember is that in a mathematical sense, functions are equal, if they produce the same output for every possible output. This is definitely true of the functions I've written above:

```
f :: Void -> Int
f _ = 1

f' :: Void -> Int
f _ = 2
```

They both give the same output for all imaginable input (which is none).

Another way to think about it is visually in the category of $Set$. I've drawn a quick picture for that purpose:

[image: Where is morphism 2?]

Yet another fun fact is that you can use $n^k$ to calculate the number of morphisms of type $K \rightarrow N, |K| = k, |N| = n$. And as we now, $n^0$ is 1 for all $n$.

Comment: for every possible "input" I think you meant.

Comment: is the mistake in my thinking by thinking of calling a function from the empty set to another set as calling a function with no argument? To me that clearly produces the constant function which has $n^1$ different values. I just don't see where I'm going wrong.

Comment: The constant function is `Unit -> X`. Also, there's no way to call an initial function in the category of Hask, and Set for that matter.